# scaled image is not showing properly at bottom right corner and using larger scale

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, zooming

I was trying an image magnifier code for my blog' s album part recently.
With `1.5` `data-scale`, the image `id=album` showed properly when hovering at top left corner.
But at bottom right corner, it shows the background instead.  Besides, when I use `2.5` `data-scale`, the image is flashing while the cursor is moving on it.
I believe it is the problem of `.on('mousemove', function(e)`, the algorithm in it is hard for me to alter.
I want the code works like the original one. Please help me modify it, thanks a lot!

[My test code](https://jsfiddle.net/4ez932hf/2/)
[Original code](http://codepen.io/ccrch/pen/yyaraz)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually when your moving your image in the `transform-origin` your moving it to quickly (you are using the height and width of the big image).

So a solution is to divide your movement factor by your scale :

```
$(this).css({'transform-origin': 
       ((e.pageX - $(this).offset().left) / $(this).width()) 
           * 100/$(this).attr('data-scale') + '% '
     + ((e.pageY - $(this).offset().top) / $(this).height()) 
           * 100/$(this).attr('data-scale') +'%'})
```

And your jsfiddle updated : https://jsfiddle.net/wpnubmah/

Comment: OMG, it works perfectly. I need to study the code for a while. BTW, thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. I understand how `transform-origin` works now. But I do not know why you use `/$(this).attr('data-scale')` in the formula because I use `((e.pageX - $(this).offset().left) / $(this).width()) * 100` which has no problem.